# Can you Implement a Singleton Pattern with a State Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, state

I have an application that I have been working on for a little while, I understand a little of Java.

The scope of the application is combine multiple design patterns in a way that allows reusability, which code can be edited without having to scroll through hundreds of lines of code.

I have implemented a true Singleton Player class.
I have also implemented a decorator weapon class.

I am not looking to add a state pattern for the player class, an example of this would be AliveState and DeadState. Something simple so I understand the workings of it all.

For the sake of this I will post the full PlayerSingleton class:

```
public class PlayerSingleton{

    private static PlayerSingleton player;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String playerName;
    private Integer playerHealth;

    private Weapon weapon;
    
    private PlayerSingleton(Weapon weapon, String pName, int pHealth) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
        playerName = pName;
        playerHealth = pHealth;
    }

    public static Weapon chooseWeapon(String choice) {
        switch (choice) {
            case "MP5":
                System.out.println("You have chosen MP5!");
                return new MP5Weapon();
            
            case "SNIPER":
                System.out.println("You have chosen Sniper!");
                return new SniperRifleWeapon();
            case "SHOTGUN":
                System.out.println("You have chosen Shotgun!");
                return new ShotgunWeapon();
            default:
                System.out.println("No gun by that name found!");
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static PlayerSingleton getInstance(String choice, String name, int health) {
        System.out.println("Choose Weapon to play the with: ");

        Weapon weapon = PlayerSingleton.chooseWeapon(choice);
        weapon.getDescription();
        if (player == null) {
            player = new PlayerSingleton(weapon, name, health);
        }
        return player;
    }

    public void getWeaponDamage(Weapon damage) { 
        System.out.println("Damage of weapon: " + weapon.damage());       
    }

    public void attackState(double damage) {
        damage = player.weapon.damage();
        
    }  
//    @Override
//    public void aliveState() {
//        if(playerHealth >= 1){
//            
//        }
//    }
//    @Override
//    public void deadState() {
//        if(playerHealth ==0){
//          System.out.println("You are dead");
//            System.out.println("GameOver");
//        }      
//    }

    public void chosenWeapon() {
        System.out.println("Player Info: " + playerName + " " + "Has: " + playerHealth + " health");
        System.out.println(weapon.getDescription() + ":" + " base damage: " + weapon.damage());
    }

    public void addBasicAttachment(String attachment) {
        switch (attachment) {
            case "SIGHT":
                weapon = new BasicSight(weapon);
                break;
            case "SILENCER":
                weapon = new BasicSilencer(weapon);
                break;
            case "STOCK":
                weapon = new BasicStock(weapon);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("No Attachment found!");
        }
    }
```

I've tried to implement this with help of Head first design patterns (State) but using the Singleton Pattern on the player class means that I cannot call the object from another class.

```
public class DeadState implements PlayerState{
PlayerSingleton player;

    public DeadState(PlayerSingleton player){
        this.player = player;
    }
    @Override
    public void deadState() {
        System.out.println("You are Dead!");
    }
    @Override
    public void aliveState() {
        System.out.println("You are Dead!");  
    }
    
}
```

Above is a test on making a DeadState implementing from a PlayerState interface.

Is there any way to do this with separate classes using the state pattern with PlayerSingleton?

Seriously any help would be amazing!

Also if you could explain the answer so I understand better.

Answer (score 1):

First of all about this sentence that you said:

> using the Singleton Pattern on the player class means that I cannot call the object from another class.

Actually you can call the object from other classes, as long as you have access to the instance, and that's how state pattern works.

I took your classes and remove some code just for the sake of simplicity and explain better the solution, you can add back the parts of the code I removed if you use this solution:

I used  the two states you have in your code, first this is the PlayerState interface, it has two methods, one for taking damage and other for respawning:

```
public interface PlayerState {
    void respawn();
    void takeDamage(int damage);
}
```

Then the implementation of Alive state has only implementation for the takeDamage method, which receives the amount of damage taken:

```
public class AliveState implements PlayerState {
    private PlayerSingleton player;

    public AliveState(PlayerSingleton player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.player.setHealth(PlayerSingleton.MAX_PLAYER_HEALTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Suffering %d damage!", damage));
        player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - damage);

        if (player.getHealth() <= 0) {
            player.setLives(player.getLives() - 1);
            player.setState(new DeadState(player));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void respawn() {
        System.out.println("Nothing to do, player is alive!");
    }

}
```

Same for the implementation of the DeadState, which has only implementation for the respawn method, as long as the player has lives left:

```
public class DeadState implements PlayerState {
    private PlayerSingleton player;

    public DeadState(PlayerSingleton player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    @Override
    public void takeDamage(int damage) {
        System.out.println("Nothing to do, player is dead!");
    }

    @Override
    public void respawn() {
        if (player.getLives() > 0) {
            System.out.println("respawning to start location!");
            player.setState(new AliveState(player));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Game Over!");
        }
    }

}
```

And finally the PlayerSingleton class, which is assigned the state AliveState when the player is created, the takeDamage and respawn methods call the implementations in the current player's state, and if you noticed, the State implementations have a reference to the player's instance, so they can change the object state.

```
public class PlayerSingleton {
    public static Integer MAX_PLAYER_HEALTH = 500;
    public static Integer DEFAULT_PLAYER_LIVES = 2;
    private static PlayerSingleton player;

    private Integer health = MAX_PLAYER_HEALTH;
    private int lives = DEFAULT_PLAYER_LIVES;
    private PlayerState playerState;

    private PlayerSingleton() {
        setState(new AliveState(this));
    }

    public static PlayerSingleton getInstance() {
        if (player == null) {
            player = new PlayerSingleton();
        }
        return player;
    }

    public void sufferDamage(int damage) {
        playerState.takeDamage(damage);
    }

    public void respawn(String location) {
        playerState.respawn();
    }
    
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

I used the following main method to test:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayerSingleton playerSingleton = PlayerSingleton.getInstance();
        playerSingleton.takeDamage(300);
        playerSingleton.respawn();
        playerSingleton.takeDamage(300);
        playerSingleton.respawn();
        playerSingleton.takeDamage(600);
        playerSingleton.respawn();
    }
```

And this was the output:

```
Suffering 300 damage!
Nothing to do, player is alive!
Suffering 300 damage!
Player is dead!
respawning to start location!
Suffering 600 damage!
Player is dead!
Game Over!
```